# Having background fit screen and maintain aspect ratio when changing browsers

Tags: html, css

I needed my background image to fit my screen, maintaining the whole image and aspect ratio in view (the image is natively 2160 by 1440) and readjust without distorting or truncating the image when I say readjust the size of my browser or view it in another browser. I have a feeling I can use the flex-box tool but am very unfamiliar with it. Does anyone know a solution to this?

Here's code I have so far:

```
<style>
body {
    background-image: url(img/index.png);
    background-size:     cover;
    background-repeat:   no-repeat;
    background-position: center center; 
}
```

Comment: add code that you try

Comment: have you tried `background-size: cover`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for background-size:cover:

```
.bg-image{
    background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/GN2OnW8.jpg);
    background-size:cover;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/x0w2a0a7/